# Docker Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections

Tags: java, database, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

While following a tutorial for  Full stack spring boot & React course. I'm currently find it difficult to get past the flyway & migrations section of the course. I currently have installed PostgreSQL on to docker on port 5432. However, I get this error response when I run my spring boot app trying to create a student table in the PostgreSQL database.

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.`

In my application.yml

```
  servlet:
    context-path: /api

app:
  datasource:
    jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/springbootdemo
    username: postgres
    password: password
    pool-size: 30
```

FYI, this is my first time utilizing docker.

Also, I have docker up & running while I run my springboot app to create the student table.

I'll appreciate all inputs on how I can solve this issue.

Comment: Guys! I vote up your post to encourage you using Docker and containers. Though,  you didn't explain many things ; what are the command that you used to run the apps, the other command to run the DB,.. ? if you are using docker-compose, what's the content of docker-compose.yaml... so on.

Comment: how did you **run** your image?

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI Thanks for the response. I was able to open the port by  using -p 5432:5432

Comment: @JovoH Just needed to open the port. Which I already did.